# Node - Is it more memory efficient to require module inside setInterval versus outside?

Tags: node.js, daemon

I have a Node file that I'm using as a service file/daemon on a Linux server.

Something like this:

```
const m = require('./local-module')

setInterval(m, duration)
```

That module exports a function, but also contains some 'global' variables, which I've noticed how those variables are the same each time the function is called, which makes sense to me.

That has me wondering whether something like:

```
setInterval(() => {
  require('./local-module')()
}), duration)
```

is more memory efficient? Does doing it one way have benefits over the other?

Answer (score 0):

Calls to `require()` are cached and will be returning the same instance. Whether you do

`var thing = require('thing'); 
thing.stuff()`
 
or

`require('thing').stuff()`

it's the same instance of "thing" each time.

For readability and convention, putting the requires at the top is more common. However, since that loads the require modules when the file loads (on app start), you might not like that for certain testing paths or mocking or initialization sequences. Doing a `require()` in the middle of you code only loads the module when called, so you can be lazy about it, which is sometimes helpful.